# Null Values from query in List

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I have a Web service that receive one list, in some cases some columns can be null and when I try insert Null values in my List I got a error. "Column is null". How I Can Insert NULL value in list if some column is null??

```
  dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  List<ClientData> myList = new List<ClientData>();
  while (dr.Read())
   {
     ClientData client = new ClientData();
     client.clientId = dr.GetString(0);
     client.ClientName = dr.GetString(1); **---> NULL VALUE**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DbDataReader.IsDBNull`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
while (dr.Read())
{
 ClientData client = new ClientData();
 client.clientId = dr.GetString(0);
 if(dr.IsDbNull(1))
     client.ClientName = null; 
 else
     client.ClientName = dr.GetString(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it is null before calling a conversion method:

```
client.ClientName = dr.IsDBNull(1) ? null : dr.GetString(1);
```